# How to give effects like flash in jquery or ccs3 slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to make my slider with jquery or ccs3 having animation effects. i have an example for slider (http://www.sifi.it).

Comment: Please refer to the [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. Your question is not valid.

Comment: you suggest me how to post question here.

Comment: Suresh - please read the link.  This question is not appropriate for this site.

Comment: you guys are not giving me any solution, just putting down my reputation. This site is made for helping other developers. Not for the purpose of giving negative marks on questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS3 transition available to animate the element like flash objects. Applying that, the element can be animate.